# How do I check all the checkboxes in the table with pagination without data table?

Tags: jquery

I want to check all the checkboxes, but when I move the checkbox page it is not checked
in here i dont user data table

this my html code

```
<table class="table table-xs table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="kpt2-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id='toogle2-check' name="optradio"></th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="kpt2-tbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this my js for get append data

```
$(element.tbody).append(`
        <tr>
            <td class="text-nowrap text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="kpt2-checkbox" data-index="${index}" data-id="${item.Id}" ${cur_checked}></td>
            <td class="text-nowrap">${index}</td>
           <td class="text-nowrap">${item.name}</td>
        </tr>
    `);
count++;
```

and this is for checking the checkbox

```
$('#toogle2-check').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //TODO: Get All Data to insert in listCheckedData ?
        $(".kpt2-checkbox").prop("checked", true);

        var curLength = $(".kpt2-checkbox:checked").length;
        $("#kpt2-total_selected").html(curLength);
    } else {
        //Clear
        listCheckedData = [];
        $(".kpt2-checkbox").prop("checked", false );

        $("#kpt2-total_selected").html($(".kpt2-checkbox:checked").length);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi what do you mean by `when I move the checkbox page...` ? Also , your current code works fine .

Comment: as I understand you want checkboxes checked only for current page. for example if you're viewing page 7 then other page checkboxes should be unchecked and the page 7 checkboxes checked.

Comment: @Nads yes, this is what I mean

Comment: @Swati My current code, only the current page is checked, but the rest of the page is not. What I want is that all the pages are closed

Comment: Please provide you complete code you're trying with.

Comment: @Nads sorry I can't display all the code, because some of it is internal, so, but my problem is more or less like that, how do you do the checkbox on page 2,3,4 .... it's also checked

Comment: Alright, How your paging(pagination) working? are you using php code for the pagination?

Comment: @Nads I use C++

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226121/discussion-between-nads-and-ruby-grv).

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert php code to your c++ code than this solution can help you in this. you just need to get current page number that's all. Although, This solution can help others who're working on the same issue with js/php.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var currentPage = 1;
var perPageRecords = 10;
var loopStart = (currentPage - 1) * perPageRecords;
var targetSelection = ((currentPage - 1) * perPageRecords) + perPageRecords;
   $('body').on('click', '#selectAll', function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) { // to know whether all checkboxes are already checked
         $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#example').prop('checked', false);
      } else {
     
       $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#example').prop('checked', false); // de select all the checkboxes
       for(let i=loopStart;i<=targetSelection; i++)
       {
       
       $('#'+i).prop('checked', true); // select only current page checkboxes
       }
       }
       $(this).toggleClass('allChecked');
     })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Checkboxes</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
         </head>
        <body>
        <?php $currenPage = 1;
              $perPageRecords = 10;
              ?>
             
        <table id="example" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>
          <button type="button" id="selectAll" class="main">
          <span class="sub"></span> Select  </button></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                                                  
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="1"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="2"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="3"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="4"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="5"/>
        </td>
      <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
      
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="6"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="7"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>
                <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="8"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="9"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="10"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test Name</td>
        <td>Test Email</td>
       
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
                        
        </body>
        </html>
```